# Android SMS Delivery Status

Tags: android, sms

I need to implement a function in my android app to send Sms messages. I found many tutorials regarding this but can NOT get the delivered status (Fail or OK). Following is my sms method.

```
 private void sendSmsMessageWithStatus(String phoneNumber, String Msg)
 {
     String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
     String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

     PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SENT), 0);
     PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(DELIVERED), 0);

     registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
     {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }               
        }

     }, new IntentFilter(SENT));

     registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver()
     {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1)
        {
            switch (getResultCode())
            {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                        
            }
        }
     }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED)); 

     SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
     sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, Msg, sentPI, deliveredPI);     
 }
```

I am checking with my google nexus 4 phone and gets the sms messages delivered properly.

I am getting the message "**SMS sent**" message but never gets "**SMS delivered**" message even when I sent successful messages to a different number.

Also the same thing when I check with the emulator (Display "**SMS sent**" message but NOT delivery status message "**SMS not delivered**").

In the manifest file I have added the permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
```

Also my development SDK versions as follows.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Does nayone know what I am doing wrong for NOT to get the Delivery status. Accoring to my code "**SMS delivered**" OR "**SMS not delivered**" messages. Thanks in advance!!!

**EDITS**

Also the sms send permission have added to manifest. missed mention that in question...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

Comment: Not every service provider offers delivery reports for SMS. Try testing your code on a different provider's device. If you're in the U.S., I believe Verizon is one that does.

Comment: You mean that's entirely up to connection service provider to support this functionality. So this way can't give the customer an indication of if message successfully delivered?      For example the android emulator which doesn't have a connection displays "SMS sent" message but NOT "SMS not delivered" message. Therefore app user can think the message delivered.

Comment: "You mean that's entirely up to connection service provider to support this functionality." - Exactly. Some do, some don't. For instance, mine does not. I don't really know if a message has been delivered until the recipient replies. If your app does receive a delivery report, then it can indicate as much, but you cannot rely on getting one on any given device/network.

Comment: To clarify a bit further, the delivery report must come from the network. If the device does not receive one from the network, your `deliveredPI` just will not fire, whether it was delivered or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Opss. Sorry I have added the sms_send permission as well. Mistakenly in question have mentioned the other one added for the test. Therfore that's not the case.